# Not able to fill Table Data (TD) element java selenium

Tags: selenium

I'm using this xpath :

```
//div[@id='shipAddrPanel-body']//td[1]//div
```

And looking to fill the first `div` .I first make sure that the object is found, so then I try to click it and send text to it.

The test gives this error message:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible .
```

Also I tried

```
//div[@id='shipAddrPanel-body']//td[1]
```

and got error :

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element .
```

Comment: Provide `HTML` code sample for mentioned `div`

Comment: If your `td[1]` element is not a direct parent of `div`, I would suggest you try to click `td[1]//div`'s ancestor nodes. Perhaps try to combine it with `Actions` class.

Comment: I tried double click on TD , it works but the div disapears before filling it .

Comment: And what method of WebElement are you using to filling the data??

Comment: rsv.getTheCountryDiv().sendKeys("test");